# Ubuntu Guest Session Works, Regular Session Not (LightDM Relog / GDM Black)

Tags: gnome, lightdm

I tried all sorts of stuff posted on forums and nothing works e.g. removing fglrx or reinstalling ubuntu-session and other packages. All done to no avail

- => I log into regular user "mashup", get thrown back to login screen
- => I log into guest session and it works

I tried unpluggin USB devices. On Gnome I get a black screen with cursor. With Light DM I get nothing (back to login)

Any ideas?

Update: I used sudo adduser username to add a new user and I can log in now. woot

Comment: This answer helped me: http://askubuntu.com/a/181420/3940